# abrt-cli reports "is not a problem directory"

Tags: linux, rhel, spoofing, abrt

we are try to remove all folders from `/var/spool/abrt/` on rhel 7.2 machines

and that after we stop the services `abrt-ccpp.service` and `abrtd.service`

because we not want any more the core under spool

but we get

```
find /var/spool/abrt/  -type d  -exec abrt-cli rm '{}' \;
'/var/spool/abrt' is not a problem directory
Can't delete '/var/spool/abrt/': (null)
'/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-12:13:41-64941' is not a problem directory
Can't delete '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-12:13:41-64941': (null)
'/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-12:16:12-2687' is not a problem directory
Can't delete '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-12:16:12-2687': (null)
'/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-14:20:09-61612' is not a problem directory
Can't delete '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-14:20:09-61612': (null)
'/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-15:12:03-55822' is not a problem directory
Can't delete '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-15:12:03-55822': (null)
```

the folder under spool are

```
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec 16 11:54 ccpp-2019-11-20-18:43:24-8768
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec 16 11:54 ccpp-2019-11-20-12:14:55-1014
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec 16 11:54 ccpp-2019-11-20-12:21:34-8475
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec 16 11:54 ccpp-2019-11-20-12:25:27-12740
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec 16 11:54 ccpp-2019-11-20-12:32:28-19585
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec 16 11:54 ccpp-2019-11-20-16:13:48-52746
```

any solution for this problem?

we also try

```
 find /var/spool/abrt/ -mindepth 1 -type d -exec abrt-cli rm '{}' \;

'/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-12:13:41-64941' is not a problem directory
Can't delete '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-12:13:41-64941': (null)
'/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-12:16:12-2687' is not a problem directory
Can't delete '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-12:16:12-2687': (null)
'/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-14:20:09-61612' is not a problem directory
Can't delete '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-14:20:09-61612': (null)
'/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-15:12:03-55822' is not a problem directory
Can't delete '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-15:12:03-55822': (null)
```

and we can see that we get the folder as

```
find /var/spool/abrt/ -mindepth 1 -type d  -print |more
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-12:13:41-64941
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-12:16:12-2687
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-14:20:09-61612
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-15:12:03-55822
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-18:37:25-2253
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-12:22:50-9886
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-13:01:41-46329
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-13:20:12-582
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-14:07:40-48870
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-15:15:23-59287
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-19:35:27-61003
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-11:22:29-12490
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-14:44:22-26098
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-11-20-17:57:35-24985
```

Comment: Is the text "is not a problem directory" something that you have translated to English yourself? It would make sense if it said "no such file or directory" since you're deleting files and directories without using `-depth`.

Comment: see the update in my question

Comment: is it ok just delete as   -->     find /var/spool/abrt/ -name  -type d -exec rm -rf {} +    ??